# Save() is prohibited to prevent data loss

Tags: django, django-views

I'm getting a **save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'** in my account views. The line with *account = form.save()* to be exact. Here's my views,  account model, and  registration form:

### Registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    steam_uid = forms.CharField(max_length=17, help_text="Required. Add a valid id")
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, help_text="Required. Add a valid email")

    class Meta:
        model = account
        fields = ('steam_uid', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        try:
            account = account.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(f"Email {email} is already in use.")
    
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            account = account.objects.get(username=username)
        except Exception as e:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(f"Username {username} is already in use.")  

class AccountAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = account
        fields = ("username", "password")
    
    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(username=username, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Login")
```

### Register view:

```
def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated: 
        return HttpResponse("You are already authenticated as " + str(user.email))

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            account = form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email').lower()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            # Account has already been authenticated at this point. Causes 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error.
            #account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            destination = get_redirect_if_exist(request)
            if destination:
                return redirect(destination)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

### Account Model:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, steam_uid, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username.")
        if not steam_uid:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a steam id.")
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            steam_uid = steam_uid,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, steam_uid, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            steam_uid = steam_uid,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



#Profile Image
def get_profile_image_filepath(self):
    return f'profile_images/{self.pk}/{"profile_image.png"}'

def get_steam_avatar_filepath(self):
    return f'media/profile_images/{self.pk}/{"steam_avatar.png"}'

def get_default_profile_image():
    return "defaulties/dummy_image.png"


class account(AbstractBaseUser):
    steam_uid = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    personaname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=False)
    profileurl = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    hide_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyAccountManager()
    __original_steam_uid = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'steam_uid']
```

The issue is within the views where account is equal to form.save(). I've tried setting form.save() to form.save(commit = false) and saving it again but I got the same issue. I'm pretty stomped here.

Comment: I'm kinda confused here. Do you mean that the form didn't save the right user? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Currently it's not saving the user, or its preventing the user from being saved because of that line of code (account = form.save()). I'm not sure if its a django issue but at one point I didn't have this issue.